# URL Rewrite is not working for dynamic url

Tags: php, iis, web-config

I have a dynamic website based on php.

In this i have url **products.php?name=unique-name&product_id=12&product_name=test-product**

i want to convert it into 
**unique-name/products/test-product/12**

i tried following code but it show 404 not found error

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/products/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="products.php?name={R:1}&product_id={R:3}&product_name={R:2}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
</rule>
```

what is wrong with my code please help me, thanks in advance

Comment: What are you using iis or apache you are using the rule of web.conifg please clear this.

Comment: iis web.config file as my server is window

Comment: Then remove htaccess tag and add web.config and iis to get better anwers.